# How to remove WebStorm?

Tags: ide

I downloaded JetBrains WebStorm and now I want to unistall it because I don't need it anymore.
I installed it by starting webstorm.sh in terminal.

But now I don't know how to remove it?

Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, if you did not changed the default location:

```
rm -rf ~/.WebStorm9
```

Comment: I start this in terminal but nothing happens((

Comment: That command deletes the folder '.Webstorm' from your user folder. Nothing else is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the marked answer is for many years ago, for versions around the year 2020 you should go to the `~` and find `.config` and `.cache` folder and then delete your specific folder version inside `JetBrains` folder:

```
~/.config/JetBrains/<product><version>
~/.cache/JetBrains/<product><version>
```